# Regex for extracting sentences with specific abbreviations

Tags: .net, regex

I just can't seem to get my head around how to do this.  I'm trying to come up with a regex (for .NET if it makes a difference) that can extract a sentence from a block of text that contains abbreviations with periods.  Basically, I want to go from a specific start word, don't stop on a defined list of abbreviations, and end at the closing period.

A couple of examples might be:

```
Blah blah blah. Died of disease at Annapolis Junction, Md., February 2, 1862. Blah blah blah.
```

would capture "Died of disease at Annapolis Junction, Md., February 2, 1862."
or

```
Blah blah blah. Died in General Hospital, Washington, D. C., September 17, 1862, of wounds received in action at Bull Run, Va., August 30, 1862. Blah Blah Blah.
```

would capture "Died in General Hospital, Washington, D. C., September 17, 1862, of wounds received in action at Bull Run, Va., August 30, 1862."

Using a simple expression of

```
Died [^\.]*\.
```

of course only matches up to the first period: "Died of disease at Annapolis Junction, Md."

The list abbreviations that need to be passed over will be from a controlled vocabulary so the regexp does not need to account for all possible abbreviations, only those in the list.  ie: Md.|D. C.|Va.|Mich.

I know the following doesn't work, but it should give a rough idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Died [^(Md\.|D\. C\.|Va\.|Mich\.)]*\.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

-Matt

Comment: Are the examples always as you showed, where the desired sentence is in the middle? If so, you could just strip out the outer sentences.

Comment: The sentences could occur just about anywhere in the text blocks and could start with any number of specific words.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to use Regex to skip over a list of things you don't want to match. You're better off looking for a different pattern.

This works with the two examples you've shown here, but I'm not sure if all your data looks like that:

```
Died.*[0-9]{4}\.
```

This basically matches "Died" and then everything up to four numbers (a date) followed by a period.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2947222/529196) ([Regex to match . (periods marking end of sentences) but not Mr. (as in Mr. Hopkins)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946045/regex-to-match-periods-marking-end-of-sentences-but-not-mr-as-in-mr-hopki))

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetSentences(string longString)
{
    var pattern = @"(?<!Md|D_C|Va|Mich|Md)\.";

    // Filter D. C. -> Replace with D_C.
    longString = longString.Replace("D. C.", "D_C.");
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    var matches = regex.Split(longString);

    var sentences = new List<string>(matches.Length);

    foreach (var match in matches)
    {
        var sentence = match.Replace("D_C.", "D. C.").Trim();
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence) == false)
        {
            sentences.Add(sentence);
        }
    }

    return sentences;
}
```

The workaround for `D. C.` is because the pattern does not match this string, hence the replacement with `D_C.`.

**Example 1**

**Input** 

`Blah blah blah. Died of disease at Annapolis Junction, Md., February 2, 1862. Blah blah blah.`

**Sentences**

- `Blah blah blah`
- `Died of disease at Annapolis Junction, Md., February 2, 1862`
- `Blah blah blah`

**Example 2**

**Input** 

`Blah blah blah. Died in General Hospital, Washington, D. C., September 17, 1862, of wounds received in action at Bull Run, Va., August 30, 1862. Blah Blah Blah.`

**Sentences**

- `Blah blah blah`
- `Died in General Hospital, Washington, D. C., September 17, 1862, of wounds received in action at Bull Run, Va., August 30, 1862`
- `Blah blah blah`